# Calling a method within a Class

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have the following class however when i try calling the method in an object, nothing happens

```
class parentClass:
  def test(self):
    if 3 > 2:
        print "This is true"
    else:
        print "This is false"
object1 = parentClass()
object1.test
```

Can someone please tel me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You're not calling it. `object1.test()` with parens, does that

Comment: referencing instead of calling, do `object1.test()`

Comment: Does it not strike you as odd that `parentClass` would require parentheses, but not `test`?

Comment: My mistake, I was blindly following a tutorial and wasn't paying close attention

Answer (score 1):

You forget "()":

```
 object1.test()
```

Remember the methods need to be called with the brackets, for example in the propierties are not need it.

Answer (score 1):

specifying a method with the parentheses just returns a reference to it. In order to call it, you need to have `()` (and optionally, any arguments) after it:

```
object1.test()
```

Answer (score 1):

add parentheses '()' to the method name where you're calling it.

object1.test()

Answer (score 1):

To call a function it requires '()'. Without these it's just a reference not a call.

```
object1.test ()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please don't just add "try this". That's not an explanation.

Comment: Much, much better :)